# When designing experiments why is it necessary to have multiple groups run in parallel?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, experiment-design

Let's say I wish to test the effectiveness of a new technique of teaching as opposed to an old one. Why is  it recommended to have a control group running the experiment in parallel with the group trying out the new technique (what is that group called :)? What is the loss if these experiments are done non-parallely? That is, we try method 1 in year 1 and method 2 in year 2 and so on. Now, the set of students would be different but that's true even if the experiment is run in parallel.

I understand that certain confounding variables could come into play and we'd like to minimize/eliminate them as much as possible. But if the costs of running the experiment with two or groups is prohibitively expensive then one may adopt for a one group at a time experiment. So if we strive to keep as many variables of the environment "constant" (to minimize confounding), can we conduct any meaningful statistical analyses on the outcomes of the experiments? (Ex.: t-tests, ANOVA etc.,) What can we say about the validity of that tests of statistical significance in this case or does it not matter?

Comment: Of course, one *can* do these things, but one is left with the potential argument that the confounders you would have eliminated with parallel design but were unable to with sequential runs were the actual explanation of the observed effect. "But of course the treatment group did better - the day of their arm of the experiment, the weather was much more comfortable; the control group struggled through sweltering conditions and the airconditioning was on the fritz; that could account for the entire effect." You have to balance up what you can do and weigh up the various kinds of costs.

Comment: But it's not just that issue; there's also the effect on variance of not-quite-as-identical-as-you'd-hope conditions; this has an effect on power; to overcome that loss of power, you'd need a larger sample size. At some point, you're going to be better off running s smaller group in parallel than running a larger group apart, while in other cases the larger-groups will be more important, but of course we can't tell which situation you might be in.

Comment: @Glen_b - Yup. That makes sense and was what I was thinking about too. For example, trying out two different methods of teaching, in the same year, is a big resource drain on the faculty members. The costs of context switching is quite high. Does this mean one is just "stuck" and pray to the gods that it's really the difference in teaching and not anything else?

Comment: You can also try to control for potential confounders - there's a lot you won't be able to keep constant from year to year. How convincing the results are depends on how complete your list looks, & on the state of knowledge in the area - "praying to the Gods" would be a pessimistic assessment in many areas of research. Also note the issue isn't about the validity of statistical tests, but about their interpretation in terms of *causes* & not just *correlations*.